# How to call C++ function from C?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, extern-c

I know this.

**Calling C function from C++:**

If my application was in C++ and I had to call functions from a library written in C. Then I would have used

```
//main.cpp

extern "C" void C_library_function(int x, int y);//prototype
C_library_function(2,4);// directly using it.
```

This wouldn't mangle the name `C_library_function` and linker would find the same name in its input *.lib files and problem is solved.

**Calling C++ function from C???**

But here I'm extending a large application which is written in C and I need to use a library which is written in C++. Name mangling of C++ is causing trouble here. Linker is complaining about the unresolved symbols. Well I cannot use C++ compiler over my C project because thats breaking lot of other stuff. What is the way out?

By the way I'm using MSVC

Comment: Read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6

Comment: When you control the C++ library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615683/calling-c-functions-from-c-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegantly call C++ from C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You need to create a C API for exposing the functionality of your C++ code. Basically, you will need to write C++ code that is declared extern "C" and that has a pure C API (not using classes, for example) that wraps the C++ library. Then you use the pure C wrapper library that you've created.

Your C API can optionally follow an object-oriented style, even though C is not object-oriented. Ex:

```c
// *.h file
// ...
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

typedef void* mylibrary_mytype_t;

EXTERNC mylibrary_mytype_t mylibrary_mytype_init();
EXTERNC void mylibrary_mytype_destroy(mylibrary_mytype_t mytype);
EXTERNC void mylibrary_mytype_doit(mylibrary_mytype_t self, int param);

#undef EXTERNC
// ...
```

```cpp
// *.cpp file
mylibrary_mytype_t mylibrary_mytype_init() {
  return new MyType;
}

void mylibrary_mytype_destroy(mylibrary_mytype_t untyped_ptr) {
   MyType* typed_ptr = static_cast<MyType*>(untyped_ptr);
   delete typed_ptr;
}

void mylibrary_mytype_doit(mylibrary_mytype_t untyped_self, int param) {
   MyType* typed_self = static_cast<MyType*>(untyped_self);
   typed_self->doIt(param);
}
```

Comment: thanks!! got it. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6

Comment: How do you link the final executable?  Do you use C or C++?  (When I used C, the linker couldn't find the C++ function; when I used C++, the linker couldn't find std::cout.)

Comment: @Zack if you create a static library with the C++ compiler/linker that transitively includes its dependencies (including the C++ standard library, which may be implicitly linked by your linker), you should be able to link that static library against C code using a C compiler/linker.

Comment: Can you export a template from C++ to C?

Comment: I have an "hybrid" behavior as I need my library to be called both by C++ and C code. In the `*.cpp file` I also needed to wrap the functions into `#ifdef _cplusplus` + `extern "C"` to avoid "undefined reference to" errors at link time.

Comment: If you want to be a bit more type safe, you can "extern C" declare a POD struct which is used on both sides, so that you don't need to deal with void pointers. I *suppose* one could even derive from that in order to have fully-fledged classes on the C++ side (with member functions). You could similarly then static_cast to the derived class (but from the base class, not void) when you call the member function wrappers.

Comment: By the way, re "C++ linker": Is there such a thing? I thought it's all the same `ld`, and the entire name decoration loops we (or rather, the compiler) jump through are there to create distinct C style functions for overloads and templates?

Comment: Last not least: I think the core idea is that the C wrappers essentially just make the first argument of member functions — `this`  — explicit. Adding that would make the perfectly correct answer even better.

Answer (score 73):

I would do it in the following way:

(If working with MSVC, ignore the GCC compilation commands)

Suppose that I have a C++ class named **AAA**, defined in files **aaa.h, aaa.cpp**, and that the class **AAA** has a method named `sayHi(const std::string &name)`, that I want to enable for C code.

#### The C++ code of class **AAA** - Pure C++, I don't modify it:

`aaa.h`

```
#ifndef AAA_H
#define AAA_H

#include <string>

class AAA {
    public:
        AAA();
        void sayHi(const std::string &name);
};

#endif
```

`aaa.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "aaa.h"

AAA::AAA() {
}

void AAA::sayHi(const std::string &name) {
    std::cout << "Hi " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this class as regularly done for C++. This code "does not know" that it is going to be used by C code. Using the command:

```
g++ -fpic -shared aaa.cpp -o libaaa.so
```

---

#### Now, also in C++, creating a C connector:

Defining it in files **aaa_c_connector.h, aaa_c_connector.cpp**. This connector is going to define a **C function with C++ implementation**, named `AAA_sayHi(cosnt char *name)`, that will use an instance of **AAA** and will call its method:

`aaa_c_connector.h`

```
#ifndef AAA_C_CONNECTOR_H 
#define AAA_C_CONNECTOR_H 

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 
void AAA_sayHi(const char *name);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif
```

`aaa_c_connector.cpp`

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "aaa_c_connector.h"
#include "aaa.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Inside this "extern C" block, I can implement functions in C++, which will externally 
//   appear as C functions (which means that the function IDs will be their names, unlike
//   the regular C++ behavior, which allows defining multiple functions with the same name
//   (overloading) and hence uses function signature hashing to enforce unique IDs),


static AAA *AAA_instance = NULL;

void lazyAAA() {
    if (AAA_instance == NULL) {
        AAA_instance = new AAA();
    }
}

void AAA_sayHi(const char *name) {
    lazyAAA();
    AAA_instance->sayHi(name);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Compiling it, again, using a regular C++ compilation command:

```
g++ -fpic -shared aaa_c_connector.cpp -L. -laaa -o libaaa_c_connector.so
```

---

Now I have a shared library (libaaa_c_connector.so), that implements the C function `AAA_sayHi(const char *name)`. I can now create a C main file and compile it all together:

`main.c`

```
#include "aaa_c_connector.h"

int main() {
    AAA_sayHi("David");
    AAA_sayHi("James");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it using a C compilation command:

```
gcc main.c -L. -laaa_c_connector -o c_aaa
```

I will need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain $PWD, and if I run the executable **./c_aaa**, I will get the output I expect:

```
Hi David
Hi James
```

EDIT:

On some linux distributions, `-laaa` and `-lstdc++` may also be required for the last compilation command. Thanks to @AlaaM. for the attention

Comment: you could also specify the lib link path with `gcc usecpp.c -L. -laaa_c_connector -Wl,-rpath,. -o c_aaa`

Comment: what's `usecpp.c`?

Comment: The last compilation line should be: `gcc main.c -L. -laaa_c_connector -laaa -lstdc++ -o c_aaa`. Note the `-laaa` and `-lstdc+++`

Comment: @AlaaM. someone edited my code and changed `main.c` to `usecpp.c`. I've just reverted it.... About the other comment, it should work also as is. The second compilation uses `-laaa` and it should probably be enough (I wrote it more than 1.5 years ago, I don't remember very well what I did, but I think I tested every line before posting)

Comment: @SomethingSomething Oh OK I understand. And I tested it with Linaro [arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries) and the 2 linking libs `-laaa` and `-lstdc++` were necessary for it to work. Otherwise I get some linking errors...

Comment: Ok, added it as a note in the end of the post. Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the C++ API is C-compatible (no classes, templates, etc.), you can wrap it in `extern "C" { ... }`, just as you did when going the other way.

If you want to expose objects and other cute C++ stuff, you'll have to write a wrapper API.

Comment: Not quite... the C++ library would need to be recompiled.

Comment: Oh no. C++ API is fully object-oriented.

Comment: @claws, see my article on making OOP-style C code.. and create a wrapper library using that style with a C interface, but an underlying C++ implementation. Then link to the C interface.

Comment: You may want to take a look at wrapper 'tools' like swig, pyboost, ... that do equivalent stuff (yet not towards C...)

Answer (score 6):

You will have to write a wrapper for C in C++ if you want to do this. C++ is backwards compatible, but C is not forwards compatible.

Answer (score 3):

export your C++ functions as extern "C" (aka C style symbols), or use the .def file format to define undecorated export symbols for the C++ linker when it creates the C++ library, then the C linker should have no troubles reading it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

//////////////
// C++ code //
//////////////
struct A
{
  int i;
  int j;

  A() {i=1; j=2; std::cout << "class A created\n";}
  void dump() {std::cout << "class A dumped: " << i << ":" << j << std::endl;}
  ~A() {std::cout << "class A destroyed\n";}
};

extern "C" {
  // this is the C code interface to the class A
  static void *createA (void)
  {
    // create a handle to the A class
    return (void *)(new A);
  }
  static void dumpA (void *thisPtr)
  {
    // call A->dump ()
    if (thisPtr != NULL) // I'm an anal retentive programmer
    {
      A *classPtr = static_cast<A *>(thisPtr);
      classPtr->dump ();
    }
  }
  static void *deleteA (void *thisPtr)
  {
    // destroy the A class
    if (thisPtr != NULL)
    {
      delete (static_cast<A *>(thisPtr));
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////
// this can be compiled as C code //
////////////////////////////////////
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *handle = createA();

  dumpA (handle);
  deleteA (handle);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider add some explanation to your answers.

Comment: A brief explanation of *how* the above answers the question makes the answer more useful to others.