# Why am I getting a namespace identifier error?

Tags: c++, namespaces, embedded, keil

I am using Keil uVision and I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\..\include\rw/_defs.h(781): error:  #20:
    identifier "namespace" is undefined
```

What could lead to this error? Isn´t namespace automatically defined?

Comment: My hunch is that you use a C compiler for your C++ program. There are no namespaces in C.

Comment: What have you done to get that error? Some more detail would be awesome... What compiler? What System? etc...

Comment: I am seeing that answer in a lot of places, but my file is a .cpp file

Comment: Is keil not a c++ compiler? @Csq

Comment: @user3729617 It would help if you would show a minimal example program and the command line options you used to compile.

Comment: @Csq:  The "issue" you linked to was merely to do with the fact that ARMCC is not C++11 compliant.  The fact that it implements C++98 is clearly stated in the documentation as is required - that has nothing to do with the problem here - it is not a compiler problem.

Comment: Also see [Namespaces in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827) and [Including C++ header file with namespace in C source file causes compilation error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16058245).

Comment: @Clifford  - it almost sounds like you are saying C++98 did not have namespaces, and you need a C++11 compiler for them. Or do you mean [inline namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11016220)?

Comment: @jww : The comment refers to a link posted in a comment now removed.  I don't know that link was, but it was as stated unrelated to this question - probably why Csq deleted it.  So I am saying nothing of the sort - the comment was not about this question, but the deleted link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using C compilation for C++ code - check the compiler options.

In C++ `namespace` is a reserved word, but not in C, so the compiler will try to interpret it as an *identifier* rather than a keyword - which will then of course make no sense syntactically to a C compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You did not expose many details but my hunch is that you use a C compiler for your C++ program. There are no namespaces in C.

I could produce similar messages with this program:

```
namespace test {
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c:1:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace test {
 ^
test.c:1:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{
' token
namespace test {
            ^
```

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/BWvXhU)