# Mixing c++ string with c

Tags: c++, c

I have a c and cpp file

**mycpp.cpp**

```
fun()
{
//code goes here....
}
```

**mycpp.h**

```
#include<string>
struct str{
std::string a;
};
func();
```

**myc.c**

```
#include "mycpp.h"

func();
//with other c codes..
```

This is a part of large code list. So it gets compiled via c++ and c. 
My problem is when mycpp.h is compiled through myc.c (which is included in myc.c) , Compiler throws an error saying **fatal error: string: No such file or directory**

Is there some wrapper mechanism to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16058799/4790490), it might help.

Comment: You're including C++ constructs in C, what do you expect? They're different languages, of course it doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot mix 2 languages. You can compile C with standard c++ compilers such as g++ but not vice-versa.

Comment: Would be helpful, if you could show us, why you included mycpp.h in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot include a C++ header file in a C file.

Declare the function `func()` with C linkage, and refer to it as an extern function inside your C file.

Example:

*mycpp.cpp*

```
void func(void)
{
    /* foo */
}
```

*mycpp.h*

```
extern "C" void func(void);
```

*myc.c*

```
extern void func(void);

/* you can now safely call `func()` */
```

You cannot use `std::string` in C, if you want to access your string, you have to pass it accordingly into your C code, by passing it a `char const*` with the contents of the string. You can get access to this string by calling `std::string::c_str()`. You can read more about `c_str()` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).