# Mixing C and C++ code

Tags: c++, c

I have a code that writes data into shared memory. I want to read this data and store it into cassandra database. The code that writes into shared memory is in C and cassandra has a C++ API. Can I now use this C++ API which is used by c code that reads the data from shared memory and calls these library functions to store it and read from casssandra?

Comment: So you are asking if C++ can read from shared memory?

Comment: I think he's asking whether his C code can call the Cassandra C++ functions.

Comment: Take a look around. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399344/calling-c-code-from-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615683/calling-c-functions-from-c-file

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. By "Can I now use this C++ API which is used by c code that... and calls ..." Do you mean "Can I now use this C++ API *from my* c code that... *in order to* ..."?

Comment: @Kristopher, I agree with Jon: seems the OP is having the XY problem :P

Comment: I guess he is asking about the point of the standards. As there are many points where c and c++ rules are corresponding. Same I asked my self some days ago, can i call a C++ functiosn from a API in c which are ok for c++ but are invalid from c standard's view.

Comment: Question should indicate platform and compiler vendor(s), as those things may may determine the answer.

Comment: http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/210/C++FAQ/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: @Jon my question was if I could write a c code that reads from the shared memory and that can call the c++ functions in the API to store into cassandra..

Comment: @Johnson I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNU c and C++ compilers...