# Incompatibility between g++ object file and gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc

- Currently, I'm creating a linux library by C program, using pthread_cleanup_push/pthread_cleanup_pop to register a clean-up function in case pthread is cancelled suddenly.
  I compiled this library source code by using g++ compiler to create ".so" file.
- I write an application in C for using this library, and build this application by g++ and gcc compiler.
- If apllication is compiled by g++, when thread is canceled then clean-up function is called successfully
- If apllication is compiled by gcc, when thread is canceled then clean-up function is NOT called
- I don't know whether g++ lib is compatible with gcc appliaction or not.
  Please help.

Comment: You need to link with `g++` when linking programs that have mixed C and C++  , this is because C++ has more startup requirements

Comment: In the latter case you are attempting to invoke C++ code from C code. Have a read of: [How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
>M.M: I tried to link with libstdc++, but it's not successfull.
>kaylum: I used C for lib and appl, I don't use C++.

Comment: @BinPhan You used `g++`. That will treat your code as C++. C and C++ are seperate languages but alot of code can be compiled as both C and C++. But the result is different. So yes, you are compiling as C++ (even though you may not have intended to) because you used `g++`.