# Using RTIMULib C++ library in C

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to control my Raspberry Pi Sense Hat with C code. Why ? Because I want to learn this language, and it's a fun project. 
But I don't find any C library. There is RTIMULib but it's a C++ library. I guess I can use g++ to compile my C program using RTIMULib but it's seems to not work with some C libraries like stdatomic.

Do you have a way to use this library in C ?

Link to the RTIMULib library : https://github.com/RPi-Distro/RTIMULib

Comment: No, you cannot not use a C++ compiler to compile C code. As much as you cannot use a Java compiler to compile C code. Same syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that it's also not possible to use this c++ library in C ^^ I hope I will find a C library... :)

Comment: I think you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c . But I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: I think there  not is any others options. I will try this, thanks.

Comment: There is a small C library that supports humidity, pressure and the LED matrix here: https://github.com/davebm1/c-sense-hat