# Get a pointer to C++ function library in c program

Tags: c++, c

In a C program I need to get a reference to a function located in a library written in C++.
Here is the part of the code

```
// Some C includes
#include <cpplib.h>
.
.
.
// A C structure attribute pointing to the C++ function
infoptr.EXT_meshAdapt = &meshAdapt;
```

The problem is the compiler tell me there is a undefined reference to `meshAdapt`, while when I do the same with a C library there is no problems.

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c) I saw we can call a C++ function in C by making a wrapper. But is there a way to refer a C++ function without making a wrapper ?

Comment: You might be able to do it by using the mangled name of the C++ function, but it seems like an ugly hack.

Comment: What do you mean ? (i don't really know C++)

Comment: If `meshAdapt` is supposed to be callable from `C`, then you should likely declare it in the header (and implement it in its lib) as `extern "C"`. The only way I see that not working is if the function needs overloads, in which case an `extern "C"` wrapper is about your only near-trivial option.

Comment: The problem is i can't modify the C++ header.

Comment: @Phantom : Are you getting only one such error? Or many undefined references? Also which compiler and what environment?

Comment: Yes, it's the only call to a C++ function in the program

Comment: @Phantom : Updated the comment, Do you have access to the source code for C++ library?

Comment: I'm under linux, using gcc. Yes I do, but it's preferable to do not change anything in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, compilers in C++ mangles the name of functions. Which means function you write to add two numbers as

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

would be mangled. ( means it would look something like `@ZVVVZaddDFD` ). So, if you want to use this function from C code then you have to call `@ZVVVZaddDFD` not `add`.

Or better option is to request the compiler to avoid mangling for your functions which you intend to use in C code.

You can do that by :-

```
extern "C"
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}
```

Comment: For this, however, he need to recompile his C++ library :D

Comment: And I can't modify the C++ header :s

Answer (score 4):

As said in other answers, C++ *mangles* the identifiers of function. This is done to allow function overloads, since different overloads get different mangled names and the linker can then identify them.

Unfortunately, name mangling is not specified by the standard, so different compilers (or different versions of a compiler) can use different mangling scheme.

So the only portable way is to declare the function itself or a wrapper around it if it could support overloads as `extern "C"` to ask the compiler to generate an unmangled identifier.

So here you could do (in C++ code):

```
extern "C" {
    int c_meshAdapt() {
        return meshAdapt();
    }
}
```

and in C code:

```
infoptr.EXT_meshAdapt = &c_meshAdapt;
```

Answer (score 1):

When compiling a C++ program, [names are mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Using an `extern "C"` block prevents the compiler from mangling what's inside of it.

Now if you don't want to use the "wrapper" `extern "C"` @Paul suggested that you used the mangled name.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the assumption that you have only one undefined reference error.

From the C++ source copy the function to which you get an undefined reference. Suppose that it is calsum() . Lets do it the C++ way.

**Create C-ified version of the function**

Write a new program say `mymath.cpp` with **just** the function. Suppose the source code for the function is below.

```
extern "C" int calsum(int x,int y) 
/*I have added an extern "C" for the reasons others suggested*/
{
return x+y;
}
```

**compile the program**

```
g++ -c mymath.cpp -o mymath.o
```

By now you should have the object code in the file `mymath.o`

**Create a library**

Do :

```
ar -src libmymath.a mymath.o
```

In the above step, you're just adding creating a static library named `libmymath.a` and adding `mymath.o` to it. See the man page for ar in case of doubt. Replace all these names with sensible names

**Finally**

Compile your C program, do

```
gcc your_c_program.c -o your_c_program.elf -L. -lmymath
```

and you're done.

Comment: The compiler seems to do not like the `extern "C"`. It expected a '(' before the `"C"`. And then I have an error `meshAdapt undeclared: first use in this function`.

Comment: Did you use the `-c` option with g++?

Comment: Yes, I used this option

Comment: @Phantom : Are you putting any other stuff into your cpp file? You just nee the function, nothing else

Comment: In the cpp there are some includes, and in the .h there are some `#define` and a `typedef struct`. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Phantom : I actually wanted to create a new cpp file with nothing in it and copy paste the function(and just the function) from the source code to this

Comment: It does not change anything