# How to call C++ functions with variable number of arguments from C code

Tags: c++, c, variadic

I have to use a third-party C++ library (that I can not change) and call its API from C code.

For most of the library APIs I use a wrapper as explained in this post:
[How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

But there is one API that takes a variable number of arguments.
Here is its definition (from the header file provided with the library):

```
void consoleDebug(char* format, ...);
```

I do not see how I can write the wrapper function for this API.
I tried this but it does not work:

```
extern "C" { 
void wrapper_consoleDebug(char * format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr,format);
    consoleDebug(format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}
}
```

Any idea is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

problem of call *c++* functions from *c* that it used different decoration.

all next for *cl.exe (msvc) + link.exe* toolset, but think other compiler/linkers have analog features

for example when you compile in *c++* function

`void consoleDebug(char* format, ...)`

in *obj* (or static *lib*) file will be `?consoleDebug@@YAXPEADZZ` symbol.
but when you use the same function from *c* unit - in object file will `_consoleDebug` (for *x86*) or `consoleDebug` (other platforms)

if we declare in *c* file

`void consoleDebug(char* format, ...)`

and do call - in *obj* will be stored that external symbol `consoleDebug` (or `_consoleDebug`) used. when linker will be build code - it will search - where is `[_]consoleDebug` actually defined (in all *obj* and *lib* passed to him) and founf nothing - no such symbol. as result we got error *unresolved external symbol `[_]consoleDebug`*

solution here in undocumented linker option **`/alternatename`** :

```
/alternatename:sym1=sym2
```

with this we say to linker (*link.exe*)  if he need `sym1` symbol and can not found it - try use `sym2` instead. with this we can create next solution:

1 - we need know exactly symbol name in *c++* - we can get it with [`__FUNCDNAME__`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2017) macro:

for example:

```
#define _GET_NAMES_

#ifdef _GET_NAMES_

void consoleDebug(char* format, ...)
{   
#pragma message(__FUNCSIG__ ";\r\n")
#pragma message("__pragma(comment(linker, \"/alternatename:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__ "\"))")
}

#endif // _GET_NAMES_
```

this is temporary, fake code, need only for print `__FUNCDNAME__`

then in *c* file we declare

```
void __cdecl consoleDebug(char *,...);

#ifdef _X86_
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:_consoleDebug=?consoleDebug@@YAXPADZZ"))
#else
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:consoleDebug=?consoleDebug@@YAXPEADZZ"))
#endif
```

and can free use `consoleDebug`

in case we have multiple functions in *c++* with same short name, say

```
void consoleDebug(char* format, ...);
void consoleDebug(wchar_t* format, ...);
```

this is also easy work, need only bit different name this 2 api in *c* code:

```
void __cdecl consoleDebugA(char *,...);

#ifdef _X86_
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:_consoleDebugA=?consoleDebug@@YAXPADZZ"))
#else
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:consoleDebugA=?consoleDebug@@YAXPEADZZ"))
#endif


void __cdecl consoleDebugW(wchar_t *,...);

#ifdef _X86_
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:_consoleDebugW=?consoleDebug@@YAXPA_WZZ"))
#else
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:consoleDebugW=?consoleDebug@@YAXPEA_WZZ"))
#endif
```

after this we can simply call like

```
consoleDebugA("str %u\n", 1);
consoleDebugW(L"str %u\n", 2);
```

from *c* code.

no any shim/wrapper code need with this. in case you use not *cl/link* but other tool-chain and can not found analog of `/alternatename` name option - possible use *asm*  file for create single `jmp` shim. say for *x64*

```
extern ?consoleDebug@@YAXPEADZZ:proc
extern ?consoleDebug@@YAXPEA_WZZ:proc

_TEXT segment 'CODE'

consoleDebugA proc 
    jmp ?consoleDebug@@YAXPEADZZ
consoleDebugA endp

consoleDebugW proc
    jmp ?consoleDebug@@YAXPEA_WZZ
consoleDebugW endp
_TEXT ENDS
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help!

I tried the suggestion from Sam Varshavchik and it works (at least in my case)! More precisely, here is what I did:

```
// wrapper.cpp
extern "C" { void (*wrapper_consoleDebug)(char * format, ...) = consoleDebug;}

// wrapper.h
extern void (*wrapper_consoleDebug)(char * format, ...);

// C file
#include "wrapper.h"

// in my code
wrapper_consoleDebug("my logger is %s","great");
```

I did not try the other suggestions yet, but I guess they would work too.

Thanks again!

Comment: This fails to account for C++ exceptions. The behavior is undefined in case a C++ exception crosses the language boundary between C++ and C. You'd have to write a C++ wrapper dealing with C++ exceptions. Doing that would make it impossible to pass the variable argument list on to the callee.

Comment: @IInspectable, agreed. In this case I got confirmation from the library developpers team that this function does not raise any exception, so I will keep this solution. Otherwise I guess I would use the suggestion from user4581301, ie "Do the formatting yourself and then call consoleDebug("%s", myFormattedBuffer);"

Comment: I wouldn't take the developers' word for this. It may be true today, but what about tomorrow? And it may not even be true today. If the function isn't allowed to have C++ exceptions escape, make them write a formal contract. In C++ you do this by using the `noexcept` specifier. As written currently, no one is checking the contract communicated to you.