# How do I call C++ functions from C?

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a C program (myapp) which needs to use a particular API; the API is written in C++. I've worked with C and C++, but never both at once, and I'm getting confused.

So, the API provides the following directory, which I've placed in a folder called include, at the same level as my makefile:

```
libmyapi.a
api/api.h
```

My main source file is src/myapp.c, and it includes the API using `#include "api/api.h"`.

My make command is (plus some flags, which I haven't listed because I don't think they're relevant here):

```
gcc  -Linclude -lmyapi -Iinclude  src/myapp.c -o lib/myapp.sp -lrt
```

The problem I'm having is that the api.h file contains references to namespaces etc. Eg at one point it has:

```
namespace MyAPI {
  namespace API {
    typedef SimpleProxyServer SimpleConnection;
  }
}
```

and obviously the C compiler doesn't know what this means.

So, I assumed I'd need to compile using a C++ compiler, but then someone said I didn't, and I could just "wrap" the code in "extern 'C'", but I don't really understand.  Having read around online, I'm not any further on.

Do I need to compile in C++ (ie using g++)?

Do I need to "wrap" the code, and what does that mean? Do I just do:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
    namespace MyAPI {
      namespace API {
        typedef SimpleProxyServer SimpleConnection;
      }
    }
  }
#endif
```

or do I just wrap the lines

```
namespace MyAPI {
      namespace API {
```

and then their corresponding }}?

The header file calls other header files, so potentially I'll need to do this in quite a lot of places.

So far I've got errors and warnings with all the variations I've tried, but I don't know whether I'm doing the wrapping wrong, setting g++ compiler flags wrong, using the wrong compiler, or what! If I know the method to use, I can at least start debugging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c)

Comment: Check out the example given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30526795/4181011 .
I think that it covers all of your questions.

Comment: It is probably easier to write an entirely new, "C compatible", interface than to try and reshape the C++ code. If the library isn't already prepared for using from C, it's unlikely that selectively sprinkling `extern "C"` over it will succeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045774/developing-c-wrapper-api-for-object-oriented-c-code and https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#call-cpp

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I've read through them, but still not certain what I'm doing. I'm following Mestkon's answer below, which seems to be close to working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a small C++ program that creates a C binding for the API.

Gvien this API:

```
namespace MyAPI {
  namespace API {
    typedef SimpleProxyServer SimpleConnection;
  }
}
```

you can create c_api.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct api_handle_t;
typedef struct api_handle_t* api_handle;
api_handle myapi_api_create();
void myapi_api_some_function_using_api(api_handle h);
void myapi_api_destroy(api_handle h);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and c_api.cpp

```
#include "c_api.h"
#include <myapi/api/stuff.hpp>

struct api_handle_t
{
    MyAPI::API::SimpleConnection c;
};

api_handle myapi_api_create()
{
    return new api_handle_t;
}

void myapi_api_some_function_using_api(api_handle h)
{ 
    //implement using h
}

void myapi_api_destroy(api_handle h) 
{
    delete h;
}
```

compile that with a C++ compiler and include the c_api.h file in the C project and link to the library you created with the C++ compiler and the original library.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: Can I ask another question? I've created c_api.cpp and include/c_api.h as outlined above. I have the original libmyapi.a in include/libs. Then I've compiled them into lapiwrapper.so using g++  -Linclude/libs -lmyapi  -shared -fPIC -D_LINUX_X86_64 -Iinclude  c_api.cpp -o include/libs/lapiwrapper.so -lrt - is that correct?  So I now have include/libs/lapiwrapper.so.

Comment: So now I go to my original code, and add "include c_api.h" into one of the headers, and compile with: gcc  -Linclude -lmyapi -lapiwrapper  -shared -DKXVER=3 -fPIC  -D_LINUX_X86_64  -Iinclude  src/myapp.c -o lib/myapp.so - this compiles with an error saying: error: unknown type name ‘api_handle_t’.  So it's finding the h file, but not the new library.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, you might need to write `typedef struct api_handle_t* api_handle;` C is picky and wont resolve struct names without explicitly writing "struct" in front of them.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't like that either. It said it was ignoring the "typedef".

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Thats a message you get when you're missing the last part of the `typedef` (e.g. `typedef struct api_handle_t*`)

Comment: You were right, I'd done it wrong - got it working now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067164/when-accessing-c-api-from-c-via-a-wrapper-how-do-i-access-enum-types - just in case you fancy explaining a bit more!

Answer (score 5):

Basically, your C++ library needs to export a pure C API. That is, it must provide an interface that relies solely on `typedef`, `struct`, `enum`, preprocessor directives/macros (and maybe a few things I forgot to mention, it must all be valid C code, though). Without such an interface, you cannot link C code with a C++ library.

The header of this pure C API needs to be compilable both with a C and a C++ compiler, however, when you compile it as C++, you must tell the C++ compiler that it is a C interface. That is why you need to wrap the entire API within

```
extern "C" {
    //C API
}
```

when compiling as C++. However, that is not C code at all, so you must hide the `extern "C"` from the C compiler. This is done by adding the preprocessor directives

```
#ifdef __cplusplus1
extern "C" {
#endif

    //C API

#ifdef __cplusplus1
}
#endif
```

If you cannot change your libraries header, you need to create a wrapper API that offers this pure C API and calls through to the respective C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ended up using Mestkon's solution, but I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I call C++ functions from C?

By writing calling functions whose declarations are valid in the common subset of C and C++. And by declaring the functions with C language linkage in C++.

> The problem I'm having is that the api.h file contains references to namespaces

Such header is not written in common subset of C and C++, and therefore it cannot be used from C. You need to write a header which is valid C in order to use it in C.

> Do I need to compile in C++ (ie using g++)?

If you have function definitions written in C++, then you need to compile those C++ functions with a C++ compiler. If you have C functions calling those C++ functions, then you need to compile those C functions with C compiler.

---

A minimal example:

```
// C++
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void function_in_cpp() {
    std::cout << "Greetings from C++\n";
}

// C
void function_in_cpp(void);

void function_in_c(void) {
    function_in_cpp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  You can use C functions in your C++ program.  But you cannot use C++ stuff from C.  When C++ was invented, it allowed for compatibility and reuse of C functions, so it was written as a superset of C, allowing C++ to call all the C library functions.

But the reverse is not true.  When C was invented, there was no C++ language defined.

The only way you can call C++ functions is to convert your whole project into a C++ one... you need to compile your C functions with a C++ compiler (or a C compiler if they are plain C) but for a C function to call a C++ function it must be compiled as C++.  You should declare it with:

```
extern "C" {

void my_glue_func(type1 param1, type2 param2, ...)
{
    /* ... */
}

} /* extern "C" */
```

and link the whole thing as a C++ program (calling the c++ linker)

This is because C doesn't know anything about *function overloading*, *class initializacion*, *instance constructor calls*, etc. So if you even can demangle the names of the C++ functions to be able to call them from C (you had better not to try this), they will probably run uninitialized, so your program may (most) probably crash.

If your `main()` function happens to be a C function, then there's no problem.  C++ was designed with this thing in mind, and so, `main()` is declared *implicitly* as `extern "C"`.  :)