# When accessing C++ API from C via a wrapper, how do I access enum types?

Tags: c++, c

I have a C program which I need to connect to a C++ API.  I asked on here and was given great advice, leading to creating a "wrapper".

So, in the API there is a type called `APIName::ReturnCode`, and I wanted to create a C equivalent, so I've done the following:

In c_api.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

typedef void* API_ReturnCode_t;
EXTERNC API_ReturnCode_t api_returncode_init();
EXTERNC void api_returncode_destroy(API_ReturnCode_t rc);

#undef EXTERNC
```

in c_api.cpp:

```
#include "c_api.h"
#include "/path/to/api/api.h"

API_ReturnCode_t api_returncode_init() {
        return new APIName::ReturnCode;
}

void api_returncode_destroy(API_ReturnCode_t untyped_ptr) {
        APIName::ReturnCode* typed_ptr = static_cast< APIName::ReturnCode*>(untyped_ptr);
        delete typed_ptr;
}
```

So I compile that into a library and include it in my main program, and I can use things like:

```
API_ReturnCode rc;
```

to define a variable.

However, my next issue is how to define enumerated types in a similar way.  So, the API has the following definition for error codes:

```
namespace APIName {

    typedef enum ReturnCode_enum ReturnCode;
    
    enum ReturnCode_enum {
        RC_OK                               ,   // success
        RC_ERROR                            ,   // general error
        RC_NOT_AVAILABLE                    ,   // feature is not available
    };
}
```

How do I recreate this in my wrapper so that I can do something like this in my code?

```
API_ReturnCode rc = API_RC_OK;
```

Comment: You want to change the enum value names?

Comment: That enum definition looks like a C programmer wrote the C++ API, which is kind of ironic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some clarification, my original answer is no longer applicable -- but is still retained below this answer.

Since the original C++ API cannot be altered in any way, you are much more limited in your available options.

You want to be able to do:

```c
API_ReturnCode rc = API_RC_OK;
```

But `rc` is an opaque type (`void*`) that requires being destroyed with `api_returncode_destroy` -- so this won't be possible in an easy and sane way (not without confusing who owns the `API_RC_OK` calls). The biggest issue is that if we could produce an `API_RC_OK` instance, it leads to questionable ownership. For example:

```c
API_ReturnCode rc = API_RC_OK;
api_returncode_destroy(rc); // is this good? is 'API_RC_OK' a resource that needs deleting?
```

And it gets more confusing in more complicated expressions.

Since the `APIName::ReturnCode_enum` type is just a classic C-style `enum`, which is implicitly convertible to an `int`, your best-bet here would be to try to preserve the `int`-like property by making `API_ReturnCode_t`'s definition be:

```c
typedef int API_ReturnCode_t;
```

Then any of the C++-wrapped calls can propagate the values as this `int`

Unfortunately to be able to receive these values on the other side, you will need to duplicate some effort here by manually re-creating these constants in some way. There are a few approaches that come to mind, all with pros and cons.

The inconvenient truth here is that, because you're trying to expose values defined in C++ in C, you'll need to somehow re-encode this on the other side in some way. You can't simply include the C++ header and use it in C, since they are different languages and C++ contains features that C doesn't understand.

### 1. Use `extern` constants

One possible approach is to use `extern const` values that get defined in the source from the underlying values, so you aren't stuck duplicating the values themselves. For example:

**c_api.h**

```c
EXTERNC extern const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_OK;
EXTERNC extern const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_ERROR;
EXTERNC extern const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE;
```

**c_api.cpp**

```cpp
extern "C" {

const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_OK = APIName::RC_OK;
const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_ERROR = APIName::RC_ERROR;
const API_ReturnCode_t API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE = APIName::RC_NOT_AVAILABLE;

} // extern "C"
```

The good thing with this approach is that you aren't stuck manually setting `API_RC_OK` to `0`, and `API_RC_ERROR` to `1`, etc -- so these values are not strongly coupled.

The thing to watch out for is that these `extern` constants would not be (safely) usable from other objects during `static` initialization, since it's not guaranteed when these values will be set. If you aren't doing much `static` initialization, this shouldn't be of any concern.

### 2. Just duplicate the effort

If the enum is not large, and not likely to grow much larger, the obvious simple approach is to just do:

```c
#define API_RC_OK 0
#define API_RC_ERROR 1
#define API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE 2
```

or some equivalent thereof. The pro is that this can be used anywhere, compared to `extern` constants. The obvious con here is that the wrapper is strongly coupled to the wrapped library. If this is a large enumeration, or an enum that is likely to change often / regularly -- this is approach is probably not the best.

### 3. Define a possibly-orthogonal enumeration

One other option is to define an orthogonal enumeration instead. This requires re-defining the enum cases that you care about, and translating them through a separate function call. This results in more effort -- so depending on what you're doing, this may not be the best case.

**c_api.h**

```c
typedef enum {
    API_RC_OK,
    API_RC_ERROR,
    API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE,
    /* other states? */
} API_ReturnCode_t;
```

**c_api.cpp

```cpp
API_ReturnCode_t to_return_code(APIName::ReturnCode rc)
{
    switch (rc) {
        case APIName::RC_OK: return API_RC_OK;
        case APIName::RC_ERROR: return API_RC_ERROR;
        case APIName::RC_NOT_AVAILABLE: return API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE;
    }
    return API_RC_NOT_AVAILABLE;
}
```

In your wrapper code, anywhere you receive an `APIName::ReturnCode` you would now translate to an `API_ReturnCode_t` before returning back to the C caller.

The nice thing about this approach is that the enumerators no longer need to be in-sync, and that you can restrict the enum cases that you want to abstract out (assuming you don't want 1-1 mapping).

This also presents an easier way to upgrade in the future to different versions of the C++ library, since everything is internalized by the translation function. If the C++ library introduces new states, you can choose to coalesce some of those values together in a way that may make it more consumable by the C client.

The obvious downside with this approach is that it takes more work, since you're defining a separate hierarchy and a translation system that will be quite similar in the beginning. It's more work up-front for a higher return later on.

---

#### Old Answer

There is nothing specific to C++ about your `ReturnCode_enum` class. It's actually written in a more legacy-C++ style (e.g. not using `enum class` for scoping), which makes it usable in C directly.

So why not define the `enum` in the `c_api.h` header file instead, and use it in your C++ as well? This may require changing your opaque handle definition depending on what is stored in it; but this way you would have exactly *1* definition of the enumeration.

You can bring the C symbol into C++ namespaces using either `typedef` or `using` aliases, which allow a more C++-esque discovery of the values.

In c_api.h:

```c
enum Api_ReturnCode_enum {
    RC_OK                               ,   /* success */
    RC_ERROR                            ,   /* general error */
    RC_NOT_AVAILABLE                    ,   /* feature is not available */
};
/* 
or 'typedef enum { ... } Api_ReturnCode_enum;' if you want don't want to specify
'enum' every time in C
*/
```

In your C++ API:

```cpp
#include "c_api.h"

namespace APIName { // bring it into this namespace:

    // Alias the "Api_" prefixed enum to be more C++ like
    typedef Api_ReturnCode_enum ReturnCode;

    // alternative, in C++11 or above:
    // using ReturnCode = Api_ReturnCode_enum;
}
```

Comment: This is better if you can modify the api headers.

Comment: This is true. The OP didn't state what parts of the API were modifiable, so I didn't really think to cover the case that it wasn't. I'll update in a little bit to cover that in my answer as well

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified, I can't modify any part of the API.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your inability to modify the API. Unfortunately I don't think there's much that you can do without duplicating the enum somewhere. Please let me know if there's anything I can expand on.

Comment: This is a nice answer

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. I'm not sure how often the API changes, but I assume that any new values would be added on to the end of the enum list, so the existing ones should continue to have the same values. I like option 3, though, as it looks safest, so I think I'll go for that.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hide error code enums in opaque handles.

Create a new enum and convertion functions in the c_api.cpp file

c_api.h

```
typedef enum {
    RC_OK,
    RC_ERROR,
    RC_NOT_AVAILABLE
} ReturnCode_copy;

ReturnCode_copy some_function(...);
```

c_api.cpp

```
static ReturnCode_copy convert(APIName::ReturnCode code) {
    switch(code) {
        //return correct ReturnCode_copy
    }
}

ReturnCode_copy some_function(...) {
    auto code = //some api function returning error code
    return convert(code);
}
```

or you could be naughty and just copy the values directly in your new enum and just static_cast directly without the convert function.

Comment: Wouldn't declaring the `enum` values like `RC_OK = SomeCppNs::Rc::Ok` be _less_ naughty?

Comment: Yes, but you need to include the cpp header in the c header to do that, which is counter productive.