# include a header file built in c++ using extern in c program

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I have a class in C++ which I want to make a shared library from it and use in C or other languages. this is the class that I want to make a library from it:

getinfo.h

```
#ifndef GETINFO_H
#define GETINFO_H
#include "info.h"

char* getMaximumSpeedCpu();
char* getCoreNumbers();
#endif
```

getinfo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "getinfo.h"
using namespace Morsa::Prd::SMC::SL;
char* getMaximumSpeedCpu()
{
    info *inf = new info;
    std::string str = inf->maximumSpeedCpu();
    char* maxspeed = new char[str.length()+1];
    strcpy(maxspeed, str.c_str());
    free(inf);
    return maxspeed;
}
char* getCoreNumbers()
{
    info *inf = new info;
    std::string corenum = inf->coreNumbers();
    char* num = new char[corenum.length()+1];
    strcpy(num, corenum.c_str());
    free(inf);
    return num;
}
```

and this is my wrapper class (smc.h):

```
#ifndef SMC_H
#define SMC_H
#include "getinfo.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
//void smc_destroy(ctestsmc *a);
char* smc_getMaximumSpeedCpu();
char* smc_getCoreNumbers();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif
#endif // SMC_H
```

smc.cpp:

```
#include "smc.h"

char *smc_getMaximumSpeedCpu()
{
   char* c = getMaximumSpeedCpu();
   return c;
}

char *smc_getCoreNumbers()
{
    char* c = getCoreNumbers();
    return c;
}
```

I made a shared library from smc.cpp, now I want to use my library in for example a C code.

How am I supposed to do it without including any header file? Whenever I include header file of smc, my C code doesn't know libraries that I had used in getinfo.h, like `fstream`.
EDIT:
info.h:

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

class info
{
private:
    std::ifstream ifile;
    std::ofstream ofile;
    std::vector<std::string> lists;
    std::string str;
    ssh_session my_ssh_session ;

public:
    info();
    info(const void *ip, const char* pw, const void *hostName);
    ~info();
    std::string maximumSpeedCpu();
    std::string coreNumbers();
    const void* _hostName;
    const void* _ip;
    const char* _password;
```

info.cpp:

```
#include "info.h"
info::info(const void *ip, const char* pw, const void *hostName)
{
    int a;
    _ip = ip;
    _password = pw;
    _hostName = hostName;
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
}
info::info()
{
}
info::~info()
{
    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}

std::string info::maximumSpeedCpu()
{
    //maximum speed of cpu
    getSSHState();
    std::string cpuSpeed;
    cpuSpeed = exec_ssh_command(my_ssh_session, "dmesg | grep 'MHz processor' | awk '{print $5}'" );
    return cpuSpeed;
}

std::string info::coreNumbers()
{
    //number of processors
    getSSHState();
    std::string coresNumber;
    coresNumber = exec_ssh_command(my_ssh_session, "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l");
    return coresNumber;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219156/discussion-on-question-by-fa7eme-include-a-header-file-built-in-c-using-extern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Theory

You can only access functions written in C from the world of C. Whenever calling C++ code from C, you must go through a wrapper function, in your case `smc_*` functions.

Now, note that the **declaration** of the wrapper functions, which is in the wrapper's header file `smc.h` does not need to include `getinfo.hpp`. *This is the key insight*. The wrapper's header merely tells any C program that includes it, the type of arguments and return values of the `smc_*` functions. The header *must stick to C*.

For example, see the image below. The functions `foo` and `bar` are declared in the `wrapper.h` file which *only* includes other C headers. The `wrapper.cpp` file which actually implements the wrapper, and uses other stuff from the C++ world (like the STL, or other classes) includes the C++ headers it needs.

In your case, `smc.cpp` will include `getinfo.hpp`, not `smc.h`.

[image]

However, the **definitions** of these wrapper functions needs to know the types of the C++ functions it is wrapping. Therefore, `smc.cpp` will include `getinfo.h`. Further, because this file will be compiled by a C++ compiler, it will understand any references to C++ STL in included headers.

### EDIT: Code example

Suppose I want to wrap the `class cppworld`.

**cppworld.hpp**:

```
class cppworld {
public:
    cppworld();
    int one();
};
```

**cppworld.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cppworld.hpp"

cppworld::cppworld() {}

int cppworld::one() {
    return 1;
}
```

I write a wrapper with `wrapper.h` and `wrapper.cpp`.

**wrapper.h**:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

int get_one();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**wrapper.cpp**:

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "cppworld.hpp"

int get_one() {
    cppworld obj = cppworld();

    return obj.one();
}
```

I can compile `wrapper.cpp` and `cppworld.cpp` into a shared library.
Then, to use the library from C, I create the C program below.

**cworld.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wrapper.h"

int main() {
    printf("Calling one() returns: %d\n", get_one());
}
```

Comment: thanks in advance for your great explanation.  about the last part that you said :` because this file will be compiled by a C++ compiler, it will be understand any references to C++ STL in included headers.` do you mean that if I include `info.hpp` in my `smc.cpp`, i don't need to use another extra wrappers for any stl or iostream usages?

Comment: Exactly. You are using two layers of wrapping (smc->getinfo->info) to use `info.hpp` functions. You only need one. `smc.cpp` can directly include `info.hpp` and use the `class info` and other C++ stuff. Just take care to use the `extern C` wrappers carefully.

Comment: @fa7eme For you, `wrapper.cpp` is `smc.cpp` and `cppworld.cpp` is `info.cpp`. `getinfo` is not needed.

Comment: is there any way to not to including header file of wrapper in c program?or using of wrapper's functions without including its header?

Comment: I found my answer here : https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_function_in_a_shared_library

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I include header file of smc, my C code doesn't know libraries that I had used in getinfo.h, like fstream.

Yeah, you need to give C the *declarations* (not the definition) of the functions you need, and those declarations cannot use C++ features (directly).

For instance, you cannot give C things like references, templates or overloaded functions. You cannot directly use arbitrary class objects either, like an `std::string`, but you can pass them around as opaque pointers since for C they are just pointers.

Regardless of how you do it, you need C to see only what appear to be C functions on the surface.

Comment: thanks in advance. you mean that I should use wrapper for using `fstream` or  `std::string` , like in `extern "C"`? how should I do that?is there any example you can give me?

Comment: @fa7eme Yes, either you pass an opaque pointer to them (like a `void *`, for instance), or you avoid having them as parameters/return types. See for instance [How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)