# How to create an object in C++ that can be referenced globally from C code?

Tags: c++, c, global, extern

I have a large program in C that I'd like to use certain C++ objects with such as maps.
I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c) on how to call C++ from C and my two C++ look like this.

```
///map.cc
#include "map.h"

void* createMap()
{
    std::map<int,int> *m = new std::map<int,int>();
    return static_cast<void*>(m);
}
void putInMap(int key, int value, void* opaque_map_ptr){
    std::map<int,int> *m = static_cast<std::map<int,int>*>(opaque_map_ptr);
    m->insert(std::pair<int,int>(key,value));
}
```

```
//map.h
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 #define EXTERNC extern "C"
 #else
 #define EXTERNC
 #endif


EXTERNC void* createMap();

EXTERNC void putInMap(int key, int value, void* opaque_map_ptr);
```

What I'm not clear about is if I do the following call in my C program, how can I be sure my Map exists and how would I make it global? Do I just make the corresponding pointer global?

```
#include "map.h"
//How do I let everyone use this map
void* ptr = createMap();
```

Comment: You have to add `extern "C"` to map.cc. `how can I be sure my Map exists and how would I make it global?` Why not just run the code as it is? Does `map.cc` includes `map.h`? Is there no `#include <map>` in `map.cc`? Why is code outside a function in the last code snippet? Is `EXTERNC` protected with `#ifdef __cplusplus`?

Comment: *"if I do the following call in my C program"* - But you can't do it. C requires all objects with static storage duration be initialized by constant expressions.

Comment: @KamilCuk Why does extern "C" need to be added to map.cc as well? The rest of the stuff exists in the real file and createMap() is being called from a large function.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Can you provide an example of what I need to modify? You can init a C++ object from C right?

Comment: Oh okay, yes map.h is included in the real file.

Comment: This is not about initializing the C++ object, it's about initializing *the pointer*. C doesn't let you call functions in initializers of static objects.

Comment: `extern "C"` does *not* have to be added to `map.cc` if you *do* include `map.h` there as well. Once having been declared as such it remains if this declaration is visible to the implementation... – the macro definition EXTERNC is pretty ugly, though, nicer is as block: `extern "C" { /* your functions here without macro */ }`. Sure, you need to protect with `#ifdef __cplusplus`, as mentioned already, as C does not know of `extern "C"`.

Comment: Off-topic: `std::pair<int, int>` is wrong for `std::map<int, bool>`... `auto m = ...` avoids repeating the type information, thus duplicate code (both functions). Maybe you might want to have a typedef (in .cc file).

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica
 The ptr is just the mechanism to access the object, following the best practice as shown in the other post. I understand you wouldn't malloc a C struct to exist at program load, but I'm not clear on how to let all my files in my program use this same map.

Comment: About the global pointer in C: Leave it default-initialised and initialise it correctly as very first thing you do in `main` function. For this, I recommend a header having the extern declaration for as usual and defining the variable in the same file as the main function.

Comment: You might, as well, try defining the variable in another C++ file (again with associated header), *there* you can initialise by calling a function, though I'm not fully sure how well that goes together with a main function written in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> //How do I let everyone use this pointer
> void* ptr = createMap();
> ```

Not by declaring a global object with an initializer that is `= createMap()`. C doesn't allow the sort of dynamic initialization of globals that C++ has. The pointer must be initialized by a constant expression. And if you want to call `createMap()` in C it can only happen after `main` is entered, and the function call made explicit.

The usual pattern for this is to provide a function that does lazy initialization and returns a pointer.

```
void *globalMap() {
    static void *ptr = NULL;
    if (!ptr)
        ptr = createMap();
    return ptr;
}
```

Calling code can then use `globalMap()` to obtain the shared pointer to the object. If "object like" syntax is required, then a macro may be used to wrap the function call

```
#define globalPtr globalMap()
```

A standard example of this can be seen with [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno).

Another thing that must be mentioned is that I wrote a very naive `globalMap()`, seeing as the pointer assignment is not thread safe. It's not impossible to *make* it thread safe, but the code will be somewhat more complex. You can have it done by the C++ compiler implicitly (C++11 and later). The technique is the so called Meyers Singleton

```
extern "C" void *globalMap() {
    static std::map<int, bool> m;
    return &m;
}
```

And that's it. The C++ compiler will instrument it such that `m` is only initialized once and without race conditions.

---

And one final note, do not forget that you must handle C++ exceptions on the ABI boundary! Making them all fatal with a bit of `noexcept` specifiers in the right place is one way, that or convert them to errors that may be returned to C code for inspection. Either way, don't ignore their existence.

Comment: Is this macro idempotent, ie can it be called by each caller utilizing the map or is it something meant to initialize a static ptr elsewhere? ```#define globalPtr globalMap()```

Comment: @knowads - The macro is as idempotent as the function itself is...