# How to successfully introduce OpenCV when compiling a C project with Clion

Tags: c, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, clion

I configured OpenCV through Cmake in Clion, but "error core.hpp header must be compiled as C++" occurred when building and compiling. This problem is in vs2022. I know how to deal with it. You can change the compile to "Compile" through the project properties of vs2022. For C++ code (/TP)" option, but I don't know how to handle it in Clion.
Program error ：`error: #error core.hpp header must be compiled as C++`
This is my Cmake configuration：

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(C006 C)

set(OpenCV_DIR D:\\ProgrammingLanguage\\openCV\\OpenCVMinGWBuild)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(C006 main.c
        HFile/suijisu.c
        HFile/suijisu.h)

target_link_libraries(C006 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I also use this type of configuration method in C++. I can successfully run the content of openCV in C++.
This is how I include OpenCV in C：

```
#ifndef C006_SUIJISU_H
#define C006_SUIJISU_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
...

#endif
```

I searched on the Internet for many ways to configure openCV in Cmake, but they always failed and reported errors.

Comment: I don't understand your question. OpenCV is a C++ library, and it cannot be used in C code. This is what the error message tells you.

Comment: Maybe I got an error message from the Internet, because I need to use openCV in C. Is there any way to enable C to use the content of openCV?

Comment: You could check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c) about calling C++ functions from C code.

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d1/dfb/intro.html): "C API is deprecated and not tested with "C" compiler since OpenCV 2.4 releases" | IIRC that has been so for at least a decade now, with some parts of the C API already removed.

Comment: In any case, the header `opencv.hpp` is definitely not the place to search C API. The extension `.hpp` is used for C++ headers only.

Comment: All C API has been removed years ago. nobody would support you in getting ancient versions to work either.