# Cannot provide link to shared library member functions

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries

Why do I encounter linker errors or undefined references when trying to link against a shared library, specifically when attempting to use member functions from the library? What are common reasons for being unable to provide a link to shared library member functions, and what strategies can be employed to resolve these issues in C++ development?

error: undefined reference to 'Init'

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 1.6.3)
PROJECT(testapp)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "test.c" )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "." )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}

libcamera-apps    )

INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libcamera_vid.h>
int main(){
int value = 1000;
char *format[]={"test.h264"};
int val = libcamera_Init(value, format);
printf("Hello");
return 0;
​
}
```

I have created a .so file and header file by using CMake but when I'm trying to use that library
to link with an application it throws error

I have created a CMake file to link a library, but I am facing issues as it does not seem to be successfully linking. What could be the potential reasons for this problem, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve the linking issues in my CMake configuration?

Comment: Looks like your problem is calling a function, defined in the C++ file, from a C code. The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c) describes approaches for that problem. If you think that you already follow that approaches (but still receive the error), then you need to include to the question post your C++ code: the place where you declare the function `libcamera_Init`, the place where you define it, and the exact error message you got.